# Заполнение контентом

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Допустим есть 9 Div-ов. Как сделать чтоб они расположились друг за другом рядами по выделенному им пространству заполняя его полностью?

Comment: Пробовали что то сделать?

Comment: как друг за другом? по горизонтале или по вертикале?

Comment: По горизонтали.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про flexbox

В зависимости от задачи, можно сделать что-то вроде этого

```css
.container {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.container__item {
width: 30%;
height: 200px;
background: red;
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.container div {
  float: left;
  width: 11%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```